# How to change linq to include href of a table cell when scraping a Table using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, linq, web-scraping

Supposing I have a table like:

```
<table class="MyClass" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="releaseCol">Name</th>
            <th class="typeCol">Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/644892" class="demo">one</a></td>
                <td class="demo">Demo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/6876" class="other">two</a></td>
                <td class="other">Compilation</td>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/8440" class="album">three</a></td>
                <td class="album">Full-length</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/610225" class="single">four</a></td>
                <td class="single">Single</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#Current code

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
{
   OptionFixNestedTags = true,
   OptionCheckSyntax = true,
   OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
};
doc.LoadHtml(html);
List<List<string>> parsedTbl = 
  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='MyClass']")
  .Descendants("tr")
  .Skip(1) //To Skip Table Header Row
  .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
  .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
  .ToList();
  foreach (var r in parsedTbl)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{r[0]} {r[1]} "); //HOW TO INCLUDE HREF INFO?
  }
```

Howshould I edit the `.Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim())` so it also includes `href` of first cell?

#expected result:

```
https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/644892  one  Demo
https://www.somescrapppage.com/x/x/x/6876    two  Compilation...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
{
   OptionFixNestedTags = true,
   OptionCheckSyntax = true,
   OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
};
doc.LoadHtml(html);

List<List<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>> parsedTbl =
              doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='MyClass']")
              .Descendants("tr")
              .Skip(1)
              .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
              .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").ToList())
              .ToList();

foreach (var r in parsedTbl)
{
   Console.WriteLine(r[0].FirstChild.Attributes["href"].Value + "  " + r[0].InnerText + "  " + r[1].InnerText); //HOW TO INCLUDE HREF INFO?
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/644892  one  Demo
https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/6876  two  Compilation
https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/8440  three  Full-length
https://www.somescrapypage.com/x/x/x/610225  four  Single
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not super pretty, but should get you started:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"index.html");
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        {
            OptionFixNestedTags = true,
            OptionCheckSyntax = true,
            OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
        };
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var results =
        doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='MyClass']")
        .Descendants("tr")
        .Skip(1) //To Skip Table Header Row
        .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1)
        .Select(tr =>
        {

            return new Result
            {
                link = tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.Elements("a").FirstOrDefault().Attributes["href"].Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                inner = tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.Elements("a").FirstOrDefault().InnerText).FirstOrDefault(),
                name = tr.Elements("td").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().InnerText
            };

        });

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Link: {result.link} InnerText: {result.inner} Name: {result.name}");
        }
    }
}

class Result
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string inner { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
}
```